# Using rallyaddnew xtype with Portfolio Items

Tags: rally

How do you use the rallyaddnew xtype with Portfolio Items?  The example shown in the documentation is for User stories.  For that it shows that recordTypes: ['User Story']

There are no examples or documentation on what to do for other items.  recordType: ['Portfolio Item'] does not seem to work, and its unclear anyway what level of Portfolio item that would create.

In my case, I'd like to create a feature level portfolio item with some fields like "expected start date" set by default by my app.  How does one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "PortfolioItem/Feature", "PortfolioItem/Theme" as the recordType(s) in the config, i.e.:

```
{
    xtype       : 'rallyaddnew',
    recordTypes : ['PortfolioItem/Feature'],
    ignoredRequiredFields: ['Name','Project'],
    showAddWithDetails: false,
    openEditorAfterAddFailure: true,
    disabled: false,
    listeners   : {
        create: function(addNew, record) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Add New', 'Added Record Name');
            console.log(record);
        }
    }
}
```

Reviewing the AppSDK2 docs, I don't see a way to populate specific fields with default values via configurable items on the component, maybe one of the Rally developers can offer some assistance on that aspect.

Comment: Thanks-- they need to extend the doc so that at least we know various options available.  This was very helpful.